# Finding the equivalence classes of a binary relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

A binary relation $\approx$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ as follows:
$$\forall x,y\in \Bbb R, x\approx y \iff \lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$$

As for finding all values of $x\in \Bbb R$ that satisfy $x^2 \in [36]$, I understand it is the set of integers. Would there be any special cases that do not fulfill the following relation?

Comment: I edited my answer, please read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Let $n$ be an integer. On what condition does $\lfloor x\rfloor = n$ ?

**Answer** : We have $\lfloor x\rfloor = n \iff x\in[n; n+1[$

Since $\lfloor x\rfloor$ always is an integer what follows is that the equivalence classes are $E_n = \{x\in \Bbb R, x\in[n; n+1[\}$ for $n \in\Bbb Z$

Thus $[36] = E_{36} = \{x\in \Bbb R, x\in[36; 37[\}$.

Therefore $$\begin{align}
x^2\in[36] &\iff 36\le x^2 \lt37\\
&\iff x \in ]-\sqrt{37}; -6]\cup [6; \sqrt{37}[
\end{align}$$

Comment: Exactly, now what can you deduce from this ?

Comment: Since $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is always an integer, the equivalence classes are $E_n = \{x\in\Bbb R, \lfloor x \rfloor = n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: The set of equivalence classes is countable and you can select a representative of each equivalence class as an integer.